# Restyling Bootstrap with Typescript styled component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap, styled-components

I have the whole Navbar basically copied from React Bootstrap. I am using Typescript's styled components in my app and I came to the point where I actually don't know how to restyle default style from Bootstrap.

**Example (React Bootstrap navabar):**

```
<Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
  <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
  <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
  <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
    <Nav className="mr-auto">
      <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
      <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
      </NavDropdown>
    </Nav>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>
```

Of course each component has to be imported form Bootstrap e.g.

```
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
```

So I can not import it again from my style.ts, where I would normally styled it. If I would use css, then of course I would give it a className and style based on that, but here is totally different system, in which I am new.

Is there any way how can I customise Bootstrap ?

I also tried React styling `style={{color: "pink"}}` to implement in elements e.g to `Nav.Link`,  but obviously it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to import navbar elements separately:

```
import {Link, Brand, etc..} from '...'
```

then you can decorated this component with styled components something like this:

```
const CustomNavLink = styled(Link)` ...props `
```

Comment: Hej @Dániel, when I am trying to import elements separately, it doesn't like it and throws an error....

Comment: @Katie I tried and you can import on the original way: import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar' then const CustomNavLink = styled(Navbar.Brand)`` use this form.